# How to get a postgresql string_to_array function working with Liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

The operative goal is to be able to compare an ID to a provided list passed in text form, e.g. "1,2,3,4,5." The thought was to simply use string_to_array to convert the input to an array and use the ANY operator on it. The issue arises because of Liquibase, when compiling the code an unexpected error occurs:

```
[ERROR] Unable to execute the query: {call testfunction(?)} 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "str286"
Where: SQL statement "select string_to_array(id_list, ',')::int[]"
PL/pgSQL function testfunction(character varying) line 10 at SQL statement
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[dao-generator.jar:?]
```

The code that generated the error is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TestFunction
(
    IN id_list VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE
(
    ID INT
)
AS
$$
DECLARE
    my_array int[4];
BEGIN
    select string_to_array(id_list, ',')::int[] into my_array;

    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT myTable.id
        FROM myTable
        WHERE myTable.parent_id = ANY(my_array);
END
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My question is how to resolve this error? Granted I am not much of a database programmer so if someone wants to recommend an alternative approach, that is also welcome.

Edits:

The call is executed as part of a liquibase compilation the changelog entries are
create_procedures entry:

```
<changeSet author="-" id="-" runAlways="true" runInTransaction="true">
        <validCheckSum>any</validCheckSum>
        <comment>Create TestFunction stored procedure.</comment>
        <sqlFile dbms="postgresql" path="-/-/-/TestFunction.sql"
                 encoding="UTF-8"
                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                 endDelimiter="go"
                 splitStatements="true"/>
    </changeSet>
```

GeneratorConfig entry:

```
<query name="TestFunction"/>
```

Comment: Note that you don't need the `select... into my_array` you can use `where parent_id = any(string_to_array(...))`

Comment: The error message "*invalid input syntax for type integer: "str286"*" is pretty obvious: you are passing strings that can't be converted to an integer. Please [edit] your question and show the code that calls the function. And a set returning function shouldn't be called with `call` but with `select * from ...`

Answer (score 0):

So after some brainstorming with the feedback from @a_horse_with_no_name, a coworker came up with a simple enough solution to get through the build process. We simply did a regex check on the input to make sure it was formatted as expected (probably not a bad idea anyway) and then altered the query according to @a_horse_with_no_name's comment.

This doesn't really answer why liquibase was testing with strings in the form of strXYZ but does at least provide a workaround in this situation